# How to achieve "paper-like" background effect?

Tags: css, photoshop

I'm a back-end developer and my design skills are admittedly very weak.  There's a CSS background effect that I really like a lot and I'm wondering if anyone could give me a general idea as to how one would achieve it?  If you look at a sites like [sourcebits.com](http://www.sourcebits.com/) or [youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com/), the background looks sort of gray and has a texture almost like a sheet of high-quality stationary.  How are they achieving this effect?

Thanks.

Comment: It's just a tiled background image. Have a look at the CSS for the BODY tag and you'll see what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS used by SourceBits:

```
body {
background: #8D9698 url('../images/body-by-bg.jpg') repeat fixed 0 0;
}
```

SourceBits background link:
http://www.sourcebits.com/images/body-by-bg.jpg

CSS used by YouTube:

```
body {
background: no-repeat url(//s.ytimg.com/yt/imgbin/www-refreshbg-vflC3wnbM.png) 0 0;
background-color: #EBEBEB;
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

YouTube background link:
http://s.ytimg.com/yt/imgbin/www-refreshbg-vflC3wnbM.png

Comment: This one works both for light and dark backgrounds (the ones recommended work in light background but have no effect on dark background): https://github.com/caph1993/GMeetMono/blob/main/paper-transparent.png
Since I use dark reader extension to switch between light and dark, I needed to edit the examples given to have a paper effect in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

They could be using a small graphic, tiled. Usually that small graphic is 10x10 pixels or smaller, and contains the background color (grey, in YouTube's case) and a few dots that are just slightly darker than the background color. When tiled, this creates a shadow effect.

Whups, @Anne got the answer in before I finished! She's also included the exact code you'll need. But, yeah, now you know the code, and you've got the 'whys' of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but this might help you a lot when you're doing front-end coding: have you ever tried using Chrome's Debugger tools? Or Firebug? That will let you see the HTML, as well as any CSS style definitions that are applied to it. It's a lot faster than viewing the source, especially helpful if front-end is not your native land because it shows you the CSS rules that apply to that specific element - backgrounds, font faces, what have you.

Comment: Thanks, Leigh.  I'll check them out.

Answer (score -2):

They use pictures, you need one for each corner and side

Comment: No, they just use a repeating background image.

Comment: it's different depending on what side you're on